# Instagram Display API Insufficient Developer Role

Tags: facebook, rest, instagram-api

I have followed the tutorial on Instagram Display API, created my redirect_uri on ngrok and correctly assign my app_id. Here is the response I get.

```
{
"error_type": "OAuthException",
"code": 400,
"error_message": "Insufficient developer role"
}
```

What should I do? I am an Administrator so I can't assign myself as a Developer.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Go to Roles > Instagram Users and add your Instagram account.  Then go to https://www.instagram.com/accounts/manage_access/ to accept the Tester Invite from your app.

Comment: To those looking at this post in 2020, the Tester accounts must be added in the Facebook Developer Page > Roles > Instagram Testers.

Comment: with help of @Linesofcode directions I've managed to get this going.. but it's effing messed up.. first: add your instagram profile slug in `Roles > Instagram testers` then go to `https://www.instagram.com/accounts/manage_access/` and on tester invite tab click `Authorize` then open link again, and then AGAIN click `authorize` to get the code.. mindblown

Comment: @Nobody, does this mean that once the App is reviewed and approved, an account can be authorized without being added as a Tester Account prior to that?

Comment: @Newskooler I was about to ask the same thing.

Comment: @Newskooler exactly i want to ask the same, Did you get the answer yet?

Comment: I also want the answer to your question. I think It should be that because I had noticed the WordPress Instagram addon where we directly authorized by plugin app without creating the app so there is no process of adding the tester Instagram accounts by these plugins.

Comment: How does this work when you're the App Admin? Cause you cannot be admin and test user at the same time?

Comment: You can also live the app and test with any account

Comment: Definitely not intuitive. The "Tester Invites" button/link appears grayed out, which makes you think it's not available. However, clicking on it showed me the waiting 'Accept' button after I added my ig account previously.

Answer (score 10):

What fixed this for me when trying to use this link:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize
  ?app_id={app-id}
  &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
  &scope=user_profile,user_media
  &response_type=code
```

... was being logged in as the accepted `Testing User` in the same browser session.

I had logged in as that user in an Incognito window, and originally the link was returning that `Insufficient Developer Role` error when I was trying it in my normal browser window.

Once tried to go to it in the incognito window, it worked just fine.

Let me know if this fixes it for you. Otherwise, I also went to my Developer Settings and did the `Individual Verification`, although my ID hasn't been approved yet and it still worked.

Answer (score 1):

I am the administrator, but I was able to fix this by adding my instagram user as a developer.

1. Meta dashboard > App roles > Roles
2. Modal appears
3. Press Developers > Add people
4. Press Instagram tester
5. Enter in my instagram id, Press Add
6. Go to https://www.instagram.com/accounts/manage_access/ > Tester
   invites tab
7. Press Accept

Answer (score 0):

So some things you really need to be careful for:

You need two accounts to make this work:

- Admin Acc (fb acc, dev.fb acc, instagram)
- Tester Acc  (fb acc, dev.fb acc, instagram)

There are two types of testers:

- TESTER
- INSTAGRAM TESTER

There are two types of ID's:

- APP ID: xxxxxxxxxx
- INSTAGRAM APP ID: xxxxxxxxx

To make sure your Instagram Basic Display works, you need to have the correct "Instagram tester". Only this option will create the tab "tester invites" in Instagram apps and websites.

Then you need to Authorize your app with the following URL:

(Add your own `instagram-app-id` and your own `redirect-uri`)

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={instagram-app-id}&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code
```

For me, it only worked by copy and pasting it into an Incognito window.

Again, important! When you use the Instagram App ID from your Admin account, you need to log in with your Tester Account or you will get an error message.