# Instagram OAuth API returns "insufficient_dev_role" 400 error

Tags: facebook, api, oauth, instagram

I have a Facebook app in Live mode, that has passed review and has Instagram Basic Display set up, having passed review for the following permissions: `instagram_graph_user_profile` and `instagram_graph_user_media`.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started), if I visit `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?app_id=[my app ID]&redirect_uri=[My app redirect URL]&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code` in a browser and authenticate, I should be redirected back to my redirect URL with a code.

However, if I try that with any user who I have not explicitly set up as an Instagram Tester, I receive the following error, even though my app is in Live mode:

```
{
"error_type": "OAuthException",
"code": 400,
"error_message": "insufficient_dev_role"
}
```

Note that another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58778302/instagram-display-api-insufficient-developer-role) was asked a few months ago - the difference in this case is that my app is in Live mode, and therefore *should* allow any user to authorise via OAuth, while for the other question the app was still in Development mode, so the issue was adding appropriate Instagram Testers.

Comment: I have the same issue! Have you managed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [has been identified](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/3240432285974194/) as a known issue that Instagram is working to fix.