# {"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Insufficient developer role"}

Tags: api, instagram

{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Insufficient developer role"}.. i am facing this issue. my facebook developer app is on dev

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Instagram Display API Insufficient Developer Role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58778302/instagram-display-api-insufficient-developer-role)